# Fluentd alternatives for IIS

Tags: windows, iis, amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, fluentd

I'm in the process of analyze my web servers logs. Everything is working fine with my Linux+Apache servers, but I need to do the same for my Windows+IIS servers. In the Fluentd's FAQ says that Windows is not supported (http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/faq#does-fluentd-run-on-windows), so I'm searching for an alternative.

Can you guys please give me some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now I have my logs sync'ed to an S3 bucket each 5 minutes.

Comment: You can check out [nxlog](http://nxlog.org/features), which supports `JSON` with the use of [the xm_json module](http://nxlog.org/nxlog-docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#xm_json). From my experience, nxlog is the most versatile log processor I know on Windows.

Comment: // , Any update on the fluentd to support IIS server logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nxlog at the each IIS servers, and aggregate into Fluentd.

- http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/windows

Answer (score 1):

Windows support is coming in Fluentd v0.14, stay tuned!